# Adding an outer gradient border or overlay shape to a circular image using CSS

Tags: html, css, border, css-gradients, css-mask

I'm attempting to add an outer gradient border of three solid colors  (**Fig B**) to an image (**Fig A**) using CSS, but am not having much luck with the methods I've tried thus far. The images will have border-radius: 50% to make them circular and the outer border needs to scale with the image. I'd like to be able to quickly apply this to any image using only a CSS class.

I've tried SVG masks, border-images, and regular overlays but none seem to accomplish the task at hand.  [This pen](https://codepen.io/markbosky/pen/mdBgGxg) is the closest I've gotten, however I need whitespace between the image and border.

```css
.img-circle{
  border-radius: 50%;
} 
.border {
  margin: 25px 0;
  /*padding: 1em;*/
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  background-size: 100% 100%, 60% 60%, 40% 40%, 25% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white),
    linear-gradient(30deg, teal 36%, teal 30%),
    linear-gradient(120deg, gold 36%, gold 30%),
    linear-gradient(210deg, blue 36%, blue 30%);
  background-position: center center, left top, right top, left bottom, right bottom;
  background-origin: content-box, border-box, border-box, border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box, border-box, border-box;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placeimg.com/280/280/any" class="border img-circle">
```

Any thoughts on how I should approach this?

[image: Example of what I'd like]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it like below. Two radial-gradient for the circles, a conic-gradient for the remaining coloration and a mask to create the gap:

```css
.img-circle{
  border-radius: 50%;
} 
.border {
  padding: 2em;
  background:
   radial-gradient(farthest-side,teal 98%,#0000) 33%  97%/1em 1em,
   radial-gradient(farthest-side,gold 98%,#0000) 100% 50%/1em 1em,
   conic-gradient(from -160deg, teal 120deg, blue 0 210deg,gold 0 250deg,#0000 0);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side, 
     #000  calc(99%  - 2em),
     #0000 calc(100% - 2em) calc(99% - 1em), 
     #000  calc(100% - 1em))
}

body {
  background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placeimg.com/280/280/any" class="border img-circle">
```